# How to track unreleased COM interfaces in a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, com

In my Visual Studio C++ project code, I obtain references to various system provided COM interfaces. I would like to make sure that I never forget to call Release() on each object when I no longer need it, and there is no accumulating leak.

Note that I don't control the source code of the COM objects, they come from the system libraries, so I cannot add any tracking code inside their implementation.

Is there a global solution, similar to the _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC compiler flag for tracking heap allocations, but for COM AddRef/Release calls?

Or are there any other solutions or tools?

Comment: You can consider to add a [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) wrapper that will call `Release` in the destructor.

Comment: Use CComPtr and friends

Comment: Since you have Visual Studio, you can use ATL to connect to these COM objects (with CComPtr), and ATL has some useful macros to debug interface leaks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/debugging-and-error-reporting-macros For the possible memory allocation issues, there's also IMallocSpy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coregistermallocspy

Comment: Use one of the provided COM pointer wrappers - MS provide `_com_ptr_t`, `MFC IPTR`, `ATL CComPtr`, `WRL ComPtr`, `wil::com_ptr` and `C++/WinRT winrt::com_ptr` - source [Old New Thing - Summary of the duck-typing requirements of C++ COM wrappers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230516-00/?p=108192)

Comment: I do use RAII wrappers, but my point is still to check if I haven't forgot to use a wrapper, or whether there is an unnoticed case when an interface remains unreleased.

Comment: I've tried to use IMallocSpy, but it gives me over 100 of "unreleased" memory allocations, which doesn't seem plausible. I guess it's not a good tool for the purpose. Besides, I'm interested in the balance of AddRef/Release calls, not actually memory allocations that happen inside of system code.

Comment: "100 unreleased" is definitely something you should consider (but it may not be your fault, it may be the called components fault). As for AddRef/Release, if they are not your components, the only thing to do is create wrappers but it's super tedious as it must be per interface (if there are TLB that's something you automate but again, lots of work). But you don't need this is you use 100% ATL's CComPtr (or other smart pointers). For your own components ATL's _ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES and _ATL_DEBUG_QI are what you'd need.

Comment: In Visual Studio, there is no flag similar to _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC, you could try to add count manually in Release, like if (Count == 0) {delete this;}